How to make JavaFX use ubuntu light font?
I am trying to use -fx-font-weight: 300 with ubuntu font. I have ubuntu regular and ubuntu light fonts in my system:


However, when I run this program:
public class FontTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var label1 = new Label("ABCDE abcde");
        label1.setStyle("-fx-font-size:18px;-fx-font-family: 'Ubuntu';-fx-font-weight: normal;");
        var label2 = new Label("ABCDE abcde");
        label2.setStyle("-fx-font-size:18px;-fx-font-family: 'Ubuntu';-fx-font-weight: 300;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(label1, label2), 400, 200);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

I get this result:

As you see both labels have same font. Could anyone say how to make JavaFX use light font?

Does -fx-font-weight: light; work?

@Slaw I tried light and got warning - Expected '<font-weight>' while parsing '-fx-font-weight'

Ah, just checked and light is not a valid value. But using 300 should be the equivalent. What do you see when you check the font property of each label? Do they contain the expected Font objects?

@jewelsea javafx.scene.text.Font.getFamilies() showed Ubuntu, Ubuntu Condensed, Ubuntu Light, Ubuntu Mono, Ubuntu Thin. And this style -fx-font-family: 'Ubuntu Light';-fx-font-weight: normal; gave light weight.

Sometimes a font weight can be selected by specifying a different -fx-font-family, not a -fx-font-weight.
This can depend on the type of font and the font families available.  For some fonts and font types, various font weights are configurable for a single font family.  But for some fonts you won't get the configuration you wish using the font weight attribute alone.
Checking installed font family names
To find available installed fonts, you can use:
javafx.scene.text.Font.getFamilies();

As noted by the asker in comments, on the asker's system, this returned:
Ubuntu, Ubuntu Condensed, Ubuntu Light, Ubuntu Mono, Ubuntu Thin

Applying the desired family
Configuring the font family with a normal font weight gave a lightweight font:
-fx-font-family: 'Ubuntu Light';
-fx-font-weight: normal;

Web fonts
A similar question and solution, but for web fonts instead of installed fonts, can be found at:

JavaFX CSS font family doesn't get applied on Label control in Xubuntu 16.04

In that question, the web font had the weight (700) specified in its lookup URL:
selection.family=Noto+Sans+SC:700

But, the matching installed font had the weight (Bold) specified in the family name:
-fx-font-family: "Noto Sans SC Bold";

